# Building a chessboard with buttons, which is always a square

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to build a chessboard consisting of buttons.
I created 3 widgets in one line. There are labels outside (filling) and inside I want to put a chessboard.
I would like it to always occupy 90% of the screen width and automatically adjust its height so that it always remains a square. It would also be necessary to set the buttons always to be squares but I also can't handle it. Can You help me?

```
class ChessBoard(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 8

        for i in range(64):
            self.cell = Button(text="", size_hint_y=self.height/8, height=self.width/8)
            self.add_widget(self.cell)

class ChessBoardContainer(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoardContainer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation='horizontal'
        self.cols=3

        self.lab1 = Label(text="1")
        self.add_widget(self.lab1)

        self.board = ChessBoard()
        self.add_widget(self.board)

        self.lab2 = Label(text="2")
        self.add_widget(self.lab2)


class CombWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CombWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'

        self.but1 = Button(text="But1", font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.but1)

        self.chessb = ChessBoardContainer()
        self.add_widget(self.chessb)

        self.but2 = Button(text="But2", font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.but2)


class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CombWidget()
```

Right now this is my result:

[image]

I would like to get something like this (Paint master ;) ). Maybe it could be done without this labels?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make buttons be squares you just have to set the height and width of GridLayout cells, and you are trying to do it with size_hint. Try this:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

class ChessBoard(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 8
        winsize = Window.size
        sizedict = {}

        # to set width and height of GridLayout cells, you should make a dict, where the key is col's/row's number and the value is size
        for i in range(self.cols):
            sizedict[i] = winsize[0]/8 #or you can divide it by 10 for example to have some black filling on the sides

        # and then simply do this
        self.cols_minimum = sizedict
        self.rows_minimum = sizedict
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I got: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: My mistake, I've edited the code, there should be: sizedict[i] = winsize[0]/8

Answer (score 0):

This code produces buttons that look fairly square to me. If you plan to use images for your chess pieces, the buttons will conform to the size of those.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

window = Tk ()
squares = []
index = 0
for x in range (8) :
    for y in range (8) :
        squares.append (Button (window, width = 7, height = 4))
        squares [index].grid (row = x, column = y)
        index += 1
window.mainloop ()
```